# CIFS Stuck at Directory Listening

Tags: networking, filesystems, cifs, samba4

I have issues with my mounted Fileshare (remote server is a SMB v3 Windows Srv 2012 Fileserver). There are multiple Folders each with around 200 to 1500 subdirectories

As soon as I want to show the content of the biggest folder (ls / du * / autocomplete)  the command stucks forever (at least 4 hours) - I only can kill the command with the -9 option.

General performance seems ok:

```
time dd if=/media/Data/BigFile.tmp  of=/dev/null bs=8k
593639+1 records in
593639+1 records out
4863092573 bytes (4.9 GB, 4.5 GiB) copied, 55.9581 s, 86.9 MB/s
```

System: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS | CPU: Xeon 2.4 Ghz | RAM: 8 GB

**fstab**

```
//server.example.local/Data /media/Data cifs credentials=/etc/samba/ad-usr,noexec,ro,sec=ntlmsspi,vers=3.0 0 0
```

I want to avoid splitting the folders content - also the Folder Browsing from my windows clients works fine

Comment: How is your connection? `df` could hang if it cannot find the directories because of the network being down.

Comment: What do you mean by "ls / df / autocomplete" please? (You can use inline formatting with backticks to differentiate `commands` from contextual grammar.)

Comment: My connection is fine - traffic is between two VMs on the same host - I can change to the direct subdirectory if I specify the subfolder path

Comment: df is a typo - I used du. With ls/df/autocomlete i mean that if I'm in the directory /media/Data/FolderWith1500Files and there I want to list the content (ls) or want to know the size (du *), or want to switch to a subfolder and type Subfol and than want to use autocomplete (tab) it stucks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the incorrect CIFS header size for SMBv2/3 (for some reason, SMBv2 works anyway) in the Linux Kernel.

This problem was fixed in kernel v4.12.11<s>, but since this is not a supported kernel release, it's on your own risk if you want to install it or not</s>.

Check https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/ChangeLog-4.12.11, look for commit 9e37b1784f2be9397a903307574ee565bbadfd75.

To install this kernel version (I see you are using Ubuntu 16.04):

1. Connect to the Linux machine via SSH/from console/etc.
2. Gain root privileges:

   sudo -i
   cd /tmp/
3. Make sure there's no other .deb package in the /tmp/ directory:

   rm -f *.deb
4. Download the kernel packages:

   wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.12.11/linux-headers-4.12.11-041211_4.12.11-041211.201709070418_all.deb  && wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.12.11/linux-headers-4.12.11-041211-generic_4.12.11-041211.201709070418_amd64.deb  && wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.12.11/linux-image-4.12.11-041211-generic_4.12.11-041211.201709070418_amd64.deb
5. Install the kernel packages:

   dpkg -i linux-*.deb
6. Reboot the server to load the new kernel.